# Should user_id be set in Configuration settings or Shared event settings in the Google Tag in GTM?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

There are at least two places to add the `user_id` parameter in the Google Tag settings in Google Tag Manager - "Configuration settings" and "Shared event settings". [There is a blog post](https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-analytics-4-user-id/#send-user-id) demonstrating that the correct place is the "Configuration parameter" area, however GTM only provides you with a checkmark and "This is a recognised parameter" when adding it to the "Shared event settings".

In debug mode, the `user_id` seemed to be sent with all events regardless of where I put it.

Where is the correct place to define the `user_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration parameter is the appropriate place to include the user_id dimension, which is a user-level dimension. This is because the user_id is a user attribute that should be sent with all events after the user_id is assigned to a user. If you want to send the user_id dimension only with specific events, you can set this parameter at the event level in your desired GA4 events tags.